# Xamarin ListView has inverted fling but normal scroll direction on android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

First of all this appears to be a known bug https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7166
Basically, you scroll normally until you lift your finger off, then the fling that normally occurs goes in the opposite direction.
That issue thread appears to have a workaround but I am brand spanking new to app development and have no clue how to implement that workaround.
So question is, how can I get the fling direction to be normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try collectionview with custom renderer as the github workaround shows :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CollectionView), typeof(ExCollectionViewRenderer))]

namespace Healx.Droid.CustomRenderer
{
    public class ExCollectionViewRenderer : CollectionViewRenderer
    {
        public ExCollectionViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            
        }
        private int dy = 0;
        public override void OnScrolled(int dx, int dy)
        {
            this.dy = dy;

            base.OnScrolled(dx, dy);
        }
        public override bool Fling(int velocityX, int velocityY)
        {

            return base.Fling(velocityX, Math.Abs(velocityY) * Math.Sign(dy));

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ItemsView> elementChangedEvent)
        {
            
            base.OnElementChanged(elementChangedEvent);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is the document about custom renderer:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview

Comment: And https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7166#issuecomment-585152206 appears to be where that code snippet is from?

Comment: Normally this would be enough for me, but something xamarin nothing i try and do to fix things on my own seems to work.
When I copy this code in almost everything is red, CollectionView doesn't even seem to exist, if I change it to ListView that exist but doesn't have OnScrolled to override.
That is why I posted this question, I saw this code snippet but simply have no clue how it's supposed to be used. Reading the docs you posted I see more stuff that just doesn't seem to exist like NativeListView.

Comment: Can you post your code about xaml and custom renderers?